# jQuery creating a click function for same classes

Tags: jquery

For example, if I want to create a jQuery function on a click for a css class "more-link", however have multiple instances of "more-link" on the page, how can I force jQuery to only run the animation on the clicked class, and not other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('element').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({
  //scope is ONLY the element clicked
  });
  $('element').animate({
    //this wi ll animate ALL elements matching the selector. Not what you want.
  });
});
```

[For anyone who finds this answer, the author actually wanted this.](http://jsfiddle.net/3c7Gy/28/)

```
$('.read-more').click(function(){
  var me = $(this);
  $(this).prev('p').animate({
     height: '100%'
  }, function(){
     //lost $(this) scope...me still holds it, we use it below for a reason.
     $(me).fadeOut(400);
     $(me).next('.hide_post-content').delay(400).fadeIn();
  });  
});
```

Comment: The only problem for this is, if I have multiple classes labeled 'more-link' then I click on, for example, the third from the first, only the first one will be animated.

Comment: @Andrew Manson [No. I'm sorry, but that's not true to any extent](http://jsfiddle.net/3c7Gy/). See the previous link for an example, Ignore the callback function I created to resize the element when I'm done with it.

Comment: I edited the code to how everyone would be set up and how I think it should be. http://jsfiddle.net/3c7Gy/24/

Comment: @Andrew Manson Give me 2 minutes

Comment: @Andrew Manson [Here's how this should actually be setup.](http://jsfiddle.net/3c7Gy/28/) Once again, you weren't referencing $(this)...as I stated in my answer. In a callback function, you lose reference to $(this), and need to declare it within the function, which is why I use `var me = $(this);` in my jsfiddle response. There you go.

Comment: That would've been useful so many times beforehand, thank you so much, it's hard attempting to learn code all by yourself, I'm only 16 :(

Comment: @Andrew Manson Strive on. You're leaps and bounds ahead of many people twice your age. Don't ever give up.

Comment: I have a another problem, http://jsfiddle.net/3c7Gy/39/ how would I close the post content back to the default 20px?

Comment: @Andrew Manson the issue is that `prev()` is only **literally** the first previous element. Because the `hide-more`'s previous element is the `read-more` div, this won't work. You have two options. you can use `.prevAll('.post-content')` But this will selet `every previous .post-content`. What you want, is to use `$(me).parent().find('.post-content').animate({height: '20px'});` [Here's the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3c7Gy/42/)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, `$(this)` refers to the element that was clicked:

```
$('.more-link').on('click', function() {
  $(this).animate(...);
});
```

Were you using `$('.more-link')` by accident?

Comment: Well, most of the time I just use the following.

Comment: `$('.more-link').click(function(){ $(this).animate(...)}; }, function({ $(this).animate(...)}); });`